# How to pass optional column in TABLE VALUE TYPE in SQL from ADF

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, table-valued-parameters

I have the following table value type in SQL which is used in Azure Data Factory to import data from a flat file in a bulk copy activity via a stored procedure.  File 1 has all three columns in it so this works fine.  File 2 only has `Column1` and `Column2`, but **NOT** `Column3`.  I figured since the column was defined as NULL it would be ok but ADF complains that its attempting to pass in 2 columns when the table type expects 3.  Is there a way to reuse this type for both files and make Column3 optional?

```
 CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TestType] AS TABLE(
    Column1 varchar(50) NULL,
    Column2 varchar(50) NULL,
    Column3 varchar(50) NULL
)
```

> Operation on target LandSource failed:
> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
> database operation failed with the following error: 'Trying to pass a
> table-valued parameter with 2 column(s) where the corresponding
> user-defined table type requires 3 column(s)

Would be nice if the copy activity behavior was consistent regardless of whether or not a stored procedure with table type is used or native BCP in the activity.  When not using the table type and using the default bulk insert, missing columns in the source file end up being NULL in the target table without error (assumming the column is NULLABLE).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390617/syntax-for-default-value-for-user-defined-type-as-table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax for Default Value for User Defined Type as Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390617/syntax-for-default-value-for-user-defined-type-as-table)

Comment: I don't have control over how ADF will call the stored procedure using the table value type.  Even though the column was NULLABLE, I used your reference to create a default value of NULL for the type, but it still complains that I'm only passing 2 values yet the type expects 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass optional column, I've made a test successfully, but the steps will be a bit complex. In my case, File 1 has all three columns, File 2 only has Column1 and Column2,  but NOT Column3. It will use Get Metadata activity, Set Variable activity, ForEach activity, IfCondition activity.

Please follow my steps:

1. You need to define a variable FileName to foreach.
   [image]
2. In the Get Metadata1 activity, I specified the file path.
   [image]
3. In the ForEach1 activity, use `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` to foreach the filelist. It need to be **Sequential**.
   [image]
4. Inside the ForEach1 activity, use Set Variable1 to set the **FileName** variable.
   [image]
5. In the Get Metadata2, use `item().name` to specify the file.
   [image]
6. In the Get Metadata2, use **Column count** to get the column count from the file.
   [image]
7. In the If Contdition1, use `@greater(activity('Get Metadata2').output.columnCount,2)` to determine whether the file is larger than two columns.
   [image]
8. In the **True** activity, use variable **FileName** to specify the file.
   [image]
9. In the **False** activity, use **Additional columns** to add a Column.
   [image]
10. When I run debug, the result shows:
    [image]

Comment: good answer. I  have exactly the same issue. I am trying to follow your steps. I cant however be able to reproduce step 2. I dont  get Child items in my look up. Where did that come from? Or has the process changed. I am happy to ask new question. We can resolve in chat and then I can post please

Comment: are you ale to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66739714/azure-data-factory-upsert-trying-to-pass-less-columns-than-the-user-defined-tab

Answer (score 1):

It will cause the mapping error in ADF.

1. In the Copy Activity, every column needs to be mapped.

[image]

2. If the source file only has two columns, it will cause mapping error.

[image]

So, I suggest you to create two different Copy activities and create a two columns table type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  If you do not map the column names, however, it's a bit more flexible.  If a column does not exist in the file but does exist in the table, it will just populate a NULL value if it is nullable.  It sounds like this is not possible right now.